# @nestjs - JwtModule.registerAsync not Registering in Time, Cant Resolve Dependencies

Tags: typescript, express, asynchronous, jwt, nestjs

Having a little trouble with the `registerAsync` functionality and `JwtModule`+`JwtService`. I looked through a lot of the other threads on this and seems like everyone was hung up on `ConfigModule`, but I am not using `ConfigModule` in this project.

Let me start with the set-up:

```
// secret-key.helper.ts

/*
  Retrieve the JWT secret value from AWS Secrets Manager. This is used to
  sign JWTs. Dont worry about imports, they're there.
*/
async function retrieveJwtSecret(): Promise<string> {
  const secretClient = new SecretsManagerClient({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });
  const getSecretCom = new GetSecretValueCommand({
    SecretId: process.env.JWT_SECRET_ARN,
  });
  const jwtSecret = (await secretClient.send(getSecretCom)).SecretString;
  return jwtSecret;
}
```

```
// auth.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { retrieveJwtSecret } from '../../utils/secret-key.helper';

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        global: true,
        secret: await retrieveJwtSecret(),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '16h' },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
// my.guard.ts

import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { logEvent } from '../log-event.helper';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtPayloadDto } from 'src/models/auth/dto/jwt-payload.dto';

@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {}
  private extractTokenFromHeader(request: Request): string | undefined {
    const [type, token] = request.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined;
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    /* JWT Authentication */
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(req);
    if (!token) {
      logEvent('ERROR: No token found.', req.headers);
      return false;
    } else {
      const payload = this.jwtService.decode(token) as JwtPayloadDto;
      logEvent('Token found.', payload);
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

So the first method is how I retrieve my JWT secret key from AWS secret manager. The second code block is the `auth` module showing the `registerAsync` global import and the usage of the `retrieveJwtSecret()` method (this is what is causing problems). The third code block is the guard I am using.

The first module where Nest runs into the Guard being imported/used returns a "can't resolve dependencies" error. When I switch away from `registerAsync` to `register`, pull the secret key in `main.ts` and place it in `process.env` manually, everything runs fine.

The exact error is:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyGuard (?).
Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [0] is available in the BenefitsModule context.

Potential solutions: ...
```

Through the use of `console.log`, I've found that execution begins in the `retrieveJwtSecret` function and that at run time, it has access to the .env variables necessary. However, it never fully completes the `const jwtSecret = await secretClient.send...` call, and my guess is that Nest continues to load modules that require `JwtModule` before Nest receives the secret and finishes setting up `JwtModule`.

I'd like to stay away from the `register` implementation I mentioned, if possible. Is there a way to force Nest to wait for `async` dependencies to be `await`-ed on?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the explicit error you're getting with this approach?

Comment: Sure thing, @JayMcDoniel. Its as follows:

`ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [0] is available in the BenefitsModule context.

Potential solutions: ...`

BenefitsModule is the first module that Nest runs into with MyGuard imported. Thats my assumption, at least.

Comment: Next time, add it to the body of the question, as it will format better. What does your `BenefitsModule` look like?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Added it to the body, thats my bad. I'm going to move away from the actual names of the Modules/Services/Controllers due to the private nature of the repo (all the code I've posted so far is only derivative of the actual source), so I'll just call that module `BModule` here.

I left BModule unchanged. I assumed due to the global register of `JwtModule` that any service/provider used by BModule or its Service/Controller (in this case, MyGuard) should have access to necessary dependencies.

So, `BModule`: 
`@Module({
  controllers: [BController],
  providers: [BService],
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`global` option of `JwtModule.registerAsync` should be on the same level as `useFactory`](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/blob/526b9a535cb225f97198c170f8d66cb01da630c3/lib/interfaces/jwt-module-options.interface.ts#L31), not a part of the options returned by the `useFactory`. So your module should be:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { retrieveJwtSecret } from '../../utils/secret-key.helper';

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      global: true,
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secret: await retrieveJwtSecret(),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '16h' },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

This will make the `JwtModule` *actually* global.

Comment: This was it, terrible of me to miss that. Thanks!

Comment: Was stumped for an hour with the exact same mistake, thanks!